# How can I add a scriptable tile at runtime to a Unity Tilemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add one of my scriptable tiles to my Unity Tilemap during runtime. I can paint the tile in the editor and everything looks fine but I would like to add it during runtime.

I tried instantiating the ScriptableObject asset itself, but it does not have the correct sprites it needs that the generated tile asset has in the editor. Also, I don't believe I should be instantiating the ScriptableObject asset for each tile since one asset is meant to be shared for all of the same tiles on the map.

The Tilemap API provides a way to add a tile, but no instructions or example of how to create the tile.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda off the top of my head, but I was messing around with something similar yesterday, instantiating a tile on click.

```
Vector3Int tilePos = map.WorldToCell(mousePos);

    YourTileClass tileInstance = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<YourTileClass>();

    Texture2D tex = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("tileTexture") as Texture2D;

    Sprite sprite = new Sprite();

    sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, 400, 400), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));

    Tile tile = Resources.Load<Tile>("tileInstance") as Tile;

    tileInstance .sprite = sprite;

    yourTileMap.SetTile(tilePos , tile);
```

I am not 100% if that is the best way to do it, but it worked for me.  Let me know if that does not work and I will double check the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment, but not knowing what you've tried so far, have you tried assigning the ruletile in the inspector and then just assigning it with SetTile at runtime whenever you need to? From the sounds of it this should achieve what you're trying to do

```
public Tilemap tilemap;
public MyRuleTile myRuleTile;
```

---

```
tilemap.SetTile(coordinate, myRuleTile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `ScriptableObject` is inheriting from `TileBase` object you can do the following:

```
 public Tilemap tilemap; 
 public TileBase tileToDraw; //Object to draw at runtime

 //Get tilemap position from the worldposition
 Vector3Int tilemapReferencePosition = tilemap.WorldToCell(reference.transform.position);//this can be the position of another gameObject e.g your Player or MousePosition

roadTileMap.SetTile(tilemapReferencePosition, tileToDraw);
```

I recently used something similar for a Fire Emblem style  RPG where I wanted to draw all the potential directions a spell can be cast before casting it and I ended up with the following function

```
public void DrawPreAttack(GameObject reference, Spell spell) {
    Vector3Int gridReferencePos = preAttackTileMap.WorldToCell(reference.transform.position);
    foreach (Vector2 direction in spell.validDirections) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= spell.maxDistance; i++) {
            preAttackTileMap.SetTile(new Vector3Int(gridReferencePos.x + (i * (int)direction.x) , gridReferencePos.y + (i * (int)direction.y) , 0), preAttackTile);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have provided two small scripts for you that show you exactly how to do this:

**1) The ScriptableObject**

After placing this script in the *Assets/???* folder, you can create new `ScriptableObjects` (or rather "ScriptableTiles") by right-clicking in the folder -> *ScriptableObjects/ScriptableTile*. After you have created such an asset, you have to "fill" it with what you want to have in it. In this case: a `Tile`. Just drag any `Tile` from your folder into the "m_Tile" slot that the `ScriptableTile` provides for you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;


[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "NewScriptableTile", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/ScriptableTile")]
public class ScriptableTile : ScriptableObject
{

    public Tile m_Tile;// Fill this with a Tile

    public bool m_IsCollider;// This does nothing, it's just a showcase for what else could be stored in here
}
```

**2) A simple "Placer"**

Attach the "Placer" `MonoBehaviour` to a `GameObject` and give it a reference to a `TileMap` and your `ScriptableTile`. On `Start()` it will place the `Tile` in the middle of the chosen `TileMap`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class ScriptableTilePlacer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Tilemap m_ExampleTileMap;

    public ScriptableTile m_ExampleTile;

    private void Start()
    {
        m_ExampleTileMap.SetTile(Vector3Int.zero, m_ExampleTile.m_Tile);
    }
}
```

I've played around with creating `TileMaps` at runtime myself - you can get even more out of `ScriptableTiles` by adding more variables. For example, if you have a separate `Collider` `TileMap`, you could use a `bool` to mark certain `Tiles` as "IsCollider" or "IsNotCollider". Another idea would be to not store `Tiles` inside the `ScriptableTile`, but `Sprites`. This allows you to completely bypass the `TilePalette` - which is pretty much useless when it comes to runtime creation. Just write a short `public Tile GetTileFromSprite()` method inside the `ScriptableTile`. With a few lines of code you can create `Tiles` from `Sprites` and return them.